# how should a unbounded integrable function be like on a bounded set?

Tags: integration, analysis

actually, my first question is could it be unbounded near boundary and we redefine the value on the boundary. For example, function $f=1/\sqrt{x}$ on $(0,1]$ and $f=0$ if $x=0$. is it integrable? Is it valid to ask such a question?(because in my textbook of definition of improper integral, we always assume it is continuous on a open set.)

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for the redefinition. $f(x) = \frac1{\sqrt x}$ is continuous on $(0,1)$ (an open set). The function is unbounded on $(0,1)$ and integrable with integral
$$\int_0^x f(t) \;\mathrm dt = 2\sqrt x$$